# data type casting in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have to convert data type from long to string in linq query join statement.
e.g.

```
 from t1 in table1

 join t2 in table2 on new {t1.field1, t1.field2} equals new {t2.field1, t2.field2} 

 select new {t1.field1,t2.field1 all columns}
```

t1.field2 is of long type and t2.field2 is of string type.
When I put ToString method it throws exception.
Exception message

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx)

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) t1.field2)
```

Comment: Thanks habib it is working fine but it is not returning the result while the SQL query is giving result on the same filter

Comment: @user1748975, you should check the generated SQL query against your LINQ expression and see what is going on

Comment: (((STR( CAST( [t1].[field2] AS float))) = [t2].[field2]) OR ((STR( CAST( [t1].[field2] AS float)) IS NULL) AND ([t2].[field2] IS NULL)))
it is adding this filter there. When I put the same filter in the SQL query it also doesn't give results

Comment: @user1748975, try StringConvert on the other field in your LINQ query