# linq version of sql with CAST to smallmoney

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a linq query to execute this query.  The column Additional Data is nvarchar(20) - so linq is reading it as a string

this works fine in SSMS

```
select SUM(CAST(AdditionalData as smallmoney)) from TransTable
where ActionID = @actID and UserID = uID;
```

this is my failed attempt at a linq version ( Decimal.Parse() can not be converted to sql from linq i guess)

```
(from a in Context.TransTable
   where a.ActionID == action.ActionID && a.UserID == (long)userId
   select decimal.Parse(a.AdditionalData)).Sum();
```

Comment: Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252717/data-type-casting-in-linq-to-sql?rq=1, seems like this is what you want to do.

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, EF, or another LINQ query provider?

Comment: linq to sql     - - - -

Comment: @CodingGorilla - that is for trying to do .ToString() - turning into a string seems much easier then parsing into decimal

Comment: What happens, does it compile, does it blew up in runtime and if so give any stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result set isn't too large you could parse the value on the client.

```
decimal value;

var sum = (from a in Context.TransTable
           where a.ActionID == action.ActionID && a.UserID == (long)userId
           select a.AdditionalValue).ToList().
           Select(x => decimal.TryParse(x, out value) ? value : 0).Sum();
```